# Firebase Storage Display Image Error On Flutter App

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

We have an app which display ads with images. We are using Firebase Storage to store the image files. The app is on production. Suddenly all images are gone and throw an exception. I cannot figure it out. Where is the problem.

Here is an example of a Card of ads.

```
child: SizedBox(
          child: ClipRRect(
            child: Hero(
              tag: '$heroTag-${ad.id}',
              child: Image.network(
                photo,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        ),
      );
```

Questions:

1. Is there any easy way to change the file types that are uploaded to Firebase Storeage.
2. How can this be possible? Suddenly all images of all ads gone.

It sound wired I know but I have no explanation. I tried to figure it out. Could anyone help and show me a path. What is going on ?

I check the file types some of them is uploaded as application/octet-stream and other images/jpeg or image/png. All types have the same error.

I can also display images from browser but not on the app. But as I said before everything works perfect 1 hour ago. Please help.

Here is the log:

```
I/flutter (25710): CacheManager: Failed to download file from https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aradiginhersey.appspot.com/o/ads%2FBQ1JpAvevJdnEhkN4oyo%2FIMG_20211108_135643.jpg?alt=media&token=713c49ad-73fd-4ac7-b023-7becb6aed2fc with error:
I/flutter (25710): SocketException: OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 104, address = firebasestorage.googleapis.com, port = 49772
```

#### Steps to reproduce

1.Create a Project

2.Add network image widget

Example: `Image.network("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aradiginhersey.appspot.com/o/ads%2FyXTZ4QWAjWjvcxPTbqCz%2FIMG-20211027-WA0040.jpg?alt=media&token=b0fa40ff-92ca-4e1a-8d68-82ea25db7470")`

3.See the error on screen.

This image can be displayed on browser.

Sign in or Sign out result is same.

#### Try to get download

```
W/ExponenentialBackoff( 6677): network unavailable, sleeping.
E/StorageUtil( 6677): error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.internal.api.FirebaseNoSignedInUserException: Please sign in before trying to get a token.
W/NetworkRequest( 6677): no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest( 6677): No App Check token for request.
V/NativeCrypto( 6677): SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb4000073a73c4988: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
W/NetworkRequest( 6677): error sending network request GET https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aradiginhersey.appspot.com/o/ads%2FyXTZ4QWAjWjvcxPTbqCz%2FIMG-20211027-WA0031.jpg
W/NetworkRequest( 6677): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb4000073a73c4988: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@214218046@21.42.18 (150400-410302452):6)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(:com.google.android.gms@214218046@21.42.18 (150400-410302452):16)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:542)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:106)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(NetworkRequest.java:417)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequestStart(NetworkRequest.java:250)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:270)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(NetworkRequest.java:289)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:113)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(ExponentialBackoffSender.java:68)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(GetDownloadUrlTask.java:77)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/NetworkRequest( 6677):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

#### Edit

When connected with VPN everything works as excepted. There is a general problem in TURKEY I think because other developers report same problem

Comment: Try to get download URL like `await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('<REFERENCE>')` and see whether it makes a difference.

Comment: I editted the question. When ı try to get download url this exception throws

Comment: Could you please keep us updated about this? I'm having the same issue in Turkey :(